# Change a user password on remote domain in PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory

I need to be able to allow users from a remote domain to change their password and I cannot install RSAT tools and the machine they will be working on.

I have tried an `Invoke-Command` passing domain admin credentials to run some code on a domain controller however I cannot get `Invoke-Command` to authenticate.

```
$InvUsername = "admin"
$InvPassword_Text = "adminpassword"
$InvPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $InvPassword_Text -Force
$InvCreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $InvUsername,$InvPassword

$InvSession = New-PSSession -ComputerName 'DC01.domain.co.uk' -Credential $InvCreds 

New-PSSession -ComputerName 'DC01.domain.co.uk' -Credential $InvCreds
New-PSSession : [DC01.domain.co.uk] Connecting to remote server DC01.domain.co.uk failed with the following error message : The user name or password is incorrect.
```

The password is not incorrect BTW.

Comment: Tried adding that domain qualifier to the username? As a test, try $InvCreds = Get-Credential and manually enter the credentials as DOMAIN\username with the password when prompted

Comment: I get the same error

Comment: It's quite possible PSSession won't work across untrusted domains. In fact this suggests not: "Briefly, the default Kerberos authentication can't work except in domains or within trust boundaries. You need to enable and specify another authentication mechanism. The safe way is to use only HTTPS and then Basic authentication. Do not use Basic with HTTP, as it will reveal credentials in clear-text."

Comment: This article seems relevant: https://serverfault.com/questions/624762/new-pssession-across-domain-boundaries

Comment: Thanks, i am just working through this article now.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to create a new remote PowerShell session to do it? Are you able to contact one of the domain controllers directly?

You could try using .NET's `DirectoryEntry` and passing credentials. If you know the `distinguishedName` of the account:

```
$user = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("LDAP://CN=user,DC=example,DC=com", $username, $password)
$user.Invoke("SetPassword","NewPassword123")
```

You may also have to tell it to explicitly connect through the LDAPS (LDAP over SSL) port like this:

```
$user = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("LDAP://DC01.domain.co.uk:636/CN=user,DC=example,DC=com", $username, $password)
```

But that also assumes that LDAPS is setup correctly with a certificate your computer trusts.

Comment: Set-ADAccountPassword is part of RSAT and i cannot install this on the machine unfortunately,

Comment: I added another way you can do it without having to install anything.

Comment: That looks promising. I will test it in the morning